# URL dispatcher: categories and drafts

Tags: django, django-urls

**Django 3.0.7**

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '<slug:categories>/',
        include(('categories.urls', "categories"), namespace="categories")
    ),
]
```

**categories/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CategoryView.as_view(), name='list'),
    re_path(r'.+', include(('posts.urls.post', "posts"), namespace="posts")),
]
```

This is my faulty attempt to write a regex to catch not less than one arbitrary symbol.

**posts/urls/post.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('draft/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="draft_detail"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

**First problem**

When I load http://localhost:8000/linux/install-os-ubuntu/, I get this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/linux/install-os-ubuntu/
Using the URLconf defined in pcask.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='home']
^admin/
polls/
applications/
draft/authors/
authors/
email/
facts/
<slug:categories>/ [name='list']
<slug:categories>/ .+ draft/<slug:slug>/ [name='draft_detail']
<slug:categories>/ .+ <slug:slug>/ [name='detail']
tags/ [name='tags']
__debug__/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, linux/install-os-ubuntu/, didn't match any of these.
```

**Another problem**

```
>>> p = Post.objects.first()
>>> p.get_absolute_url()
'/news/.efremov/'
```

That is a dot appeared in the url.

What is going on here and how can I organize:

1. http://localhost:8000/linux/ routes to CategoryView.
2. Anything else goes to PostDetailView with urls like:

   - http://localhost:8000/linux/draft/install-os-ubuntu/
   - http://localhost:8000/linux/install-os-ubuntu/

Comment: In my architecture any post has a category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you've got it that regex;

```
re_path(r'.+', include(('posts.urls.post', "posts"), namespace="posts")),
```

To illustrate the issue, the following paths are included on the above path;

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('draft/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="draft_detail"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

The `posts` include matches 1 or more character except line breaks. So to match a post with the slug `my-post` you would have the following URLs;

```
/a/my-post/

/b/my-post/

/c/my-post/
```

I think the regex here is causing the confusion. To match this against your examples you'd have;

> a) http://localhost:8000/linux/a/draft/install-os-ubuntu/

> b) http://localhost:8000/linux/b/install-os-ubuntu/

What I would do is to set out your URLs something like this;

Categories;

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('list/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('', include(('posts.urls.post', "posts"), namespace="posts")),
]
```

It's also worth noting that you can test out your regex here; https://regexr.com/

It'll even explain what your regex is doing which is often invaluable as they're hardly straightforward!!